# Creating subscription plans charging connected accounts using stripe

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I basically want to create subscription plans where I can charge the connected accounts and give them additional benefits on the platform in return. Because the connected accounts are businesses, they are not registered as customers on the platform. Is there a proper way to do this through stripe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your options here basically are to either register them as Customers as well and use Subscriptions, or potentially use [Account Debits](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/account-debits) and your own recurring mechanism.